# What version of swift is used in legacy swift for xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a)?

Tags: swift, xcode, legacy

What version of swift is used in legacy swift for xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a)? How can I check this? I tried:

xcrun swift -version

But it only returned Swift 3.0:

Apple Swift version 3.0 (swiftlang-800.0.46.2 clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9

How can I check the version of Swift that is used when I write an app in Legacy Swift code?

Comment: Swift Version 2.3

Answer (score 0):

yes all swift 3.0 codes are working since the version is 3.0